# I'm trying to export the dimensions of a custom kitchen cabinet parts in cm!

Tags: export, dimensions, csv

I came up with this code by studying in StackExchange previous questions and answers,

code:

```
import bpy

file = open("/home/user/Blender/MyFile_01.csv", 'w')
selectedObjects = bpy.context.selected_objects
file.write('Panel name\t height\t width\t thickness\n')

for obj in selectedObjects:
    dim = obj.dimensions
    file.write(obj.name+'\t'+'{:.3f}\t{:.3f}\t{:.3f}\n'.format(dim.x,dim.y,dim.z))

file.close()
print(obj)
```

and here's a screenshot of csv opened in excel-alike program using (Tab) as a separator between columns so i can use this file to generate a cutlist in MaxCut software.

[image]

**my question is:**
how can i show numbers in cm instead of meter by fixing my code?

like this picture which i modified in excel

[image]

Comment: `file.write(obj.name+'\t'+'{:.3f}\t{:.3f}\t{:.3f}\n'.format(dim.x*100,dim.y*100,dim.z*100))`

Comment: **it worked fine**
many thanks Hikariztw

where can i find more information about these expressions ?

Comment: **Python**, as a programming language. It will be very useful if you can write python in a lot of thing.